# c# winform background worker and progress bar

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I am trying to get the progress bar to increment using a BG Worker.
I am currently using 2 BG workers, one to add data into a DB and one for the progress bar.  The DB upload is working fine, yet the progress bar is not.

Code:

```
BackgroundWorker bg2 = new BackgroundWorker();
bg2.DoWork +=new DoWorkEventHandler(bg2_DoWork);
bg2.RunWorkerAsync();

void bg2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        while (bg1.IsBusy)
            DrawWellPlate.pbar.Increment(1)
    }
```

bg1 that it refers to is the database upload thread and pbar is clearly the progress bar.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you get any exception? or just your UI was freezed?

Comment: No exception, just no progress on the bar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do something like this
where totalProgress will be shown in progressBar, doWork is executed not in UI thread, that is the purpose of BackgroundWorker

```
BackgroundWorker bg2 = new BackgroundWorker();
bg2.DoWork +=new DoWorkEventHandler(bg2_DoWork);
.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bg2_ProgressChanged)
bg2.RunWorkerAsync();

void bg2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        while (bg1.IsBusy)
            worker.ReportProgress(totalProgress);
    }
private void bg2_ProgressChanged(object sender,
            ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            DrawWellPlate.pbar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }
```

see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) for more details

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that bg1 will **always** report that it is busy while it runs its DoWork method.

You should use just ONE background worker and in its do work method something like this (pseudo code):

```
void bg1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while(got_stuff_to_add_to_the_database)
    {
       //do *some* of the work
       AddABit()

       //Update the progress - 5% at a time?
       totalProgress += 5

       //update the progress bar
       ReportProgress(totalProgress)

       if(finished)
       {
           got_stuff_to_add_to_the_database = false;
       }
    }
}
```